# `go test` succeed for individual tests but fails when testing package

Tags: macos, unit-testing, go, mocking

When I run single test with `go test -run TestNewProbeServiceIsSingleton` it passes as expected.

Problem occurs whenever I am trying to test the whole package/app using `go test ./...` from my project's root directory:

```
madjlzz@MadSfeirLab $ go test ./...              
?       github.com/madjlzz/madprobe     [no test files]
ok      github.com/madjlzz/madprobe/controller  (cached) [no tests to run]
?       github.com/madjlzz/madprobe/internal/alerter    [no test files]
?       github.com/madjlzz/madprobe/internal/mock       [no test files]
?       github.com/madjlzz/madprobe/internal/persistence        [no test files]
--- FAIL: TestInsertReturnErrorOnGetFailure (0.00s)
panic: Fail in goroutine after TestNewProbeServiceIsSingleton has completed [recovered]
        panic: Fail in goroutine after TestNewProbeServiceIsSingleton has completed [recovered]
        panic: Fail in goroutine after TestNewProbeServiceIsSingleton has completed

goroutine 23 [running]:
testing.tRunner.func1(0xc0000f6400)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.6/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:874 +0x3a3
panic(0x12ccca0, 0xc000095190)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.6/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:679 +0x1b2
github.com/golang/mock/gomock.(*Controller).Finish(0xc000098ff0)
        /Users/madjlzz/Documents/Projects/Go/pkg/mod/github.com/golang/mock@v1.4.3/gomock/controller.go:246 +0x2b2
panic(0x12ccca0, 0xc000095190)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.6/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:679 +0x1b2
testing.(*common).Fail(0xc0000f6200)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.6/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:609 +0x151
testing.(*common).FailNow(0xc0000f6200)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.6/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:631 +0x2b
testing.(*common).Fatalf(0xc0000f6200, 0x1351581, 0x2e, 0xc0000c4140, 0x5, 0x5)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.6/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:716 +0x90
github.com/golang/mock/gomock.(*Controller).Call.func1(0xc000098de0, 0x1301ca0, 0xc000094f90, 0x1343807, 0x3, 0xc000095110, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        /Users/madjlzz/Documents/Projects/Go/pkg/mod/github.com/golang/mock@v1.4.3/gomock/controller.go:201 +0x486
github.com/golang/mock/gomock.(*Controller).Call(0xc000098de0, 0x1301ca0, 0xc000094f90, 0x1343807, 0x3, 0xc000095110, 0x1, 0x1, 0x5, 0xc00008a660, ...)
        /Users/madjlzz/Documents/Projects/Go/pkg/mod/github.com/golang/mock@v1.4.3/gomock/controller.go:217 +0xb4
github.com/madjlzz/madprobe/internal/mock.(*MockPersister).Get(0xc000094f90, 0x134426b, 0x7, 0x16, 0x0, 0x0)
        /Users/madjlzz/Documents/Projects/Go/src/github.com/madjlzz/madprobe/internal/mock/entity.go:53 +0xe5
github.com/madjlzz/madprobe/internal/prober.(*service).Insert(0xc000098e70, 0x134426b, 0x7, 0x1348f2d, 0x16, 0x0, 0x0, 0x5, 0xc00008a660, 0x156df40, ...)
        /Users/madjlzz/Documents/Projects/Go/src/github.com/madjlzz/madprobe/internal/prober/service.go:63 +0x19b
github.com/madjlzz/madprobe/internal/prober.TestInsertReturnErrorOnGetFailure(0xc0000f6400)
        /Users/madjlzz/Documents/Projects/Go/src/github.com/madjlzz/madprobe/internal/prober/service_test.go:59 +0x4fb
testing.tRunner(0xc0000f6400, 0x135be98)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.6/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:909 +0xc9
created by testing.(*T).Run
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.6/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:960 +0x350
FAIL    github.com/madjlzz/madprobe/internal/prober     0.287s
?       github.com/madjlzz/madprobe/util        [no test files]
FAIL
```

App builds without any errors:

```
madjlzz@MadSfeirLab $ go build .   
madjlzz@MadSfeirLab $
```

My Golang version is:

```
madjlzz@MadSfeirLab $ go version
go version go1.13.6 darwin/amd64
```

I am using also `mockgen` to mock my interfaces in version `1.4.3`

I am new to Golang but it feels I kinda miss something on how to run tests...

You can also run the tests by yourself by cloning the [project](https://github.com/MadJlzz/madprobe/tree/bug/testing)

Comment: This is hard to debug without code, but the fact alone that you are working with a singleton is a red flag. Another test might be mutating the singleton's value, leading to the crash.

Comment: You have the code available in GitHub here: https://github.com/MadJlzz/madprobe/tree/bug/testing.

So it means that golang is sharing the memory between multiple tests ? If this is the case, that might be a problem since I am using `sync.Once` and one of my mocked function is called inside `Do()` of `sync.Once`...

Comment: Is there any real compelling reason to use a singleton? The only place where `NewProbeService` is used is in your main function, so maybe a better fix might be to just not use the singleton pattern and spare yourself the pain that comes with it :)

Comment: "So it means that golang is sharing the memory between multiple tests?" - Yes, it is. It all runs in one process.

Comment: @deR_Ed, well there is one that might break the app if someone (me), is creating multiple `ProbeService`. But you guys are right, I am gonna remove that pattern to stay simple. I'll cover the breaking case in another way :)


@Zyl, yup so now it's all clear, I have to be careful next time. Good job pinpointing the problem!

Comment: @MadJlzz what fix did you do? Facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume ur code looks like (I had such problem):

```
for _, subtest := range subtests{
   t.Run(subtest.name,
        func(t *testing.T) {
           do something with subtest...
        }
}
```

But it must look like:

```
for _, s := range subtests{
   subtest:=s

   t.Run(subtest.name,
        func(t *testing.T) {
           do something with subtest...
        }
}
```

Attention on **subtest:=s**

This is one of the possible solutions in this situation.

Comment: i have the same problem, few tests that are part of same suite are breaking when run together, but running fine individually. Your fix also does not work for me.